# Is randomized input data less prone to the exploding gradient problem?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to train a RNN but I'm running into NaN errors while training. I think that this is due to the gradients exploding, although I can't confirm this. As a simple test, I fed random data with the same dimensions as my prepared data to the network, and I was surprised to see the NaNs go away.

Is it true that more random data are less likely to cause exploding gradients? I thought that more learnable data would be less likely to diverge, is this not the case?

Comment: Why don't you just alter your algorithm so it prints out the gradient it uses in every step? Most implementation has some control value you can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now what implementation are using, but you can have NAN's if you have missing data, or data with 0 variance (e.g all ones). Also you will usually get some warnings, when there are NANs produced, so it would be a good idea to read them.